# Store data in offset register 386 masm

Tags: assembly, masm, i386

So for my problem I have to shift values from one array to the other, with the output array being the shifted result,

like:

```
input byte 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
shift dword 4 ; doesnt matter the value as long as its less than the length of input.
output byte LENGTHOF input DUP(?)

;so after I shift the array the result should be

5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4
```

The code I have right now does this in a loop but I keep getting `A2032: invalid use of register`

```
xor eax, eax        ; clear EAX
xor ebx, ebx        ; clear EBX
xor ecx, ecx        ; clear ECX
xor edx, edx        ; clear EDX
mov ecx, shift      ; mov the Shift variable to ECX

M1:
            neg ecx 
            mov al, input[LENGTHOF input + ecx]
            mov edx[ebx], al                          ; this is the errored line
            neg ecx
            inc ebx
loop M1
```

I cant find any way to directly offset on the register so that EDX holds the final array. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: You need to write that as `mov [edx+ebx], al`. Although it's unclear what you want that to do as you have zeroed both `edx` and `ebx` so that's not going to be a valid address.

Comment: Yea it keeps yelling at me because I dont have permissions to write to the register it gets.
`Exception thrown at 0x00511024 in assembly.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00511005.`

Comment: You can always modify any of the 8 GP-integer registers.  Writing to a memory location pointed to by a register is another matter.  It looks like your faulting code address was very close to the data address reported in the exception, specifically in the same 4k page, so probably you were trying to write to read-only memory in the code segment.

Comment: I'm wondering if `input` and `output` buffers were declared in the code segment instead of the data segment, which would explain the write violation. The buffers need to be in the data segment. If using dot directives, it would be the .data segment. `output` could be in .data?, the uninitialized segment. Pinging @PeterCordes  on this comment.